# Highlight differences in words in df cells

Tags: python, string, string-comparison, python-docx, pandas-styles

I have a df that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Before':['one three four', 'apple banana milk'], 
               'After': ['one two three four five', 'soda banana apple juice milk'], 
               'Difference': ['two, five', 'soda, juice']})
```

In this df there are three columns, with text before changing, after and also column that store differences.

How can I highlight words in column `df['After']` if these words are in `df['Difference']` and save it to excel/docx(table) ?

Expected output like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight" ? Put those words in red in the output excel ?

Comment: Yes, any type of "highlight" (red words/bold words/italic words)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that pandas doesn't provide a way to easily change the color of a substring. Since pandas tables are displayed using HTML and CSS, you would need to manually change the HTML data of `df.to_html()`. That way, a cell `<td>one two three four five</td>` could be changed to `<td>one <span style="color: #ff0000">two</span> three four <span style="color: #ff0000">five</span></td>`. Then you could do

```py
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(html_string)
```

to display the table with colored text. However, I didn't find a way to import it back into pandas, so that one could export it to excel, but you could try importing the HTML data in Excel directly.

It would be much easier if you could separate the words to multiple columns. Then you could use [`df.style.apply(func, axis=1, subset=['After', 'Difference'])`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html), which iterates over each row and changes the style of cells to export it normally.